# Core ML Fetching decryption key from server failed

Tags: ios, coreml, mlmodel

I have an app with encrypted core ML model. App was working fine and was decrypting model properly. After app update on my device it has started giving following error

```
[coreml] Could not create persistent key blob for EFD428E8-CDE7-4E0A-B379-FC169E50DE4D : error=Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=8 "Fetching decryption key from server failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching decryption key from server failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80ab0 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=6 "CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKRetryAfter=35, NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80000 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=2022 "Request failed with http status code 503" UserInfo={CKRetryAfter=35, CKHTTPStatus=503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503}}, CKHTTPStatus=503}}}

[coreml] MLModelAsset: load failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=8 "Fetching decryption key from server failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching decryption key from server failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80ab0 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=6 "CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKRetryAfter=35, NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80000 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=2022 "Request failed with http status code 503" UserInfo={CKRetryAfter=35, CKHTTPStatus=503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503}}, CKHTTPStatus=503}}}

[coreml] MLModelAsset: modelWithError: load failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=8 "Fetching decryption key from server failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching decryption key from server failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80ab0 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=6 "CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, CKRetryAfter=35, NSUnderlyingError=0x281d80000 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=2022 "Request failed with http status code 503" UserInfo={CKRetryAfter=35, CKHTTPStatus=503, CKErrorDescription=Request failed with http status code 503, RequestUUID=D5CF13CF-6A10-436B-AB93-4C5C04859FFE, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed with http status code 503}}, CKHTTPStatus=503}}}
```

Somehow fetching decryption key from server is failing. I have tried deleting app, restarting device but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I has got the same error , it turn to normal last night, so it should be a owner error with the Apple server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had to wait about 30 minutes, before it worked. Then only the newly added model worked, but the existing ones signed with the same newly created file still didn't work, maybe because they had been signed before with another key. So i had to remove them from the project. Add them again, and add "--encrypt /path/to/model.mlmodelkey" again to the Build Phases->Compile Sources entries.

Comment: Problem is that it's released on appstore. If user also face similar kind of problem it is a very bad user experience for the app.